# What parameters are used to create VM in proxmox using Api

Tags: c#, proxmox

I am trying to create a vm in proxmox using API provided by Proxmox VE.
But this Api has methods only for creating starting stopping and deleting containers.
in order to create a VM i have defined my own function

```
    public IRestResponse<Upid> CreateVm(VMTemplate template)
    {
        var client = new RestClient(_baseUrl);
        var request = new RestRequest($"nodes/{_node}/qemu", Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("CSRFPreventionToken", _apiTicket.CSRFPreventionToken);
        request.AddCookie("PVEAuthCookie", _apiTicket.ticket);
        //request.RootElement = "data";
        request.AddParameter("cores", template.cores);
        request.AddParameter("sata0", template.sata0);
        request.AddParameter("ide2", template.ide2);
        request.AddParameter("memory", template.memory);
        request.AddParameter("name", template.name);
        request.AddParameter("net0", template.net0);
        request.AddParameter("ostype", template.ostype);
        request.AddParameter("numa", template.numa);
        request.AddParameter("scsihw", template.scsihw);
        request.AddParameter("sockets", template.sockets);
        var response = client.Execute<Upid>(request);
        return response;
    }
```

but in response it is giving an error

> "Parameter verification failed."

which parameter i am missing?
or is there any other mistake?

Comment: What the API documentation says?

Comment: i am following this link 
https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Proxmox_VE_API

Comment: it gives a link to git hub project and in that project there is no documentation but in the above shared link there is a documentation link from which i get the path to node and qemu
    "nodes/{_node}/qemu"
here's the link for documentation
https://pve.proxmox.com/pve-docs/api-viewer/index.html

Comment: Muhammad Fahad did you manage to figure it out?